# Objective C to Swift code conversion, can't seem to treat bytes correctly in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bluetooth

I'm working on a simple Swift bluetooth heart rate monitor iOS App. I found [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/52080/introduction-core-bluetooth-building-heart-rate-monitor) great tutorial which has objective C code. I've converted it to Swift and I'm getting data from my heart rate monitor. My problem is that I can't seem to correctly access and convert the byte data in Swift.

Here's the Objective C code:

```
// Instance method to get the heart rate BPM information
- (void) getHeartBPMData:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error
{
    // Get the Heart Rate Monitor BPM
    NSData *data = [characteristic value];      // 1
    const uint8_t *reportData = [data bytes];
    uint16_t bpm = 0;

    if ((reportData[0] & 0x01) == 0) {          // 2
        // Retrieve the BPM value for the Heart Rate Monitor
        bpm = reportData[1];
    }
    else {
        bpm = CFSwapInt16LittleToHost(*(uint16_t *)(&reportData[1]));  // 3
    }
    // Display the heart rate value to the UI if no error occurred
    if( (characteristic.value)  || !error ) {   // 4
        self.heartRate = bpm;
        self.heartRateBPM.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i bpm", bpm];
        self.heartRateBPM.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Futura-CondensedMedium" size:28];
        [self doHeartBeat];
        self.pulseTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(60. / self.heartRate) target:self selector:@selector(doHeartBeat) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    }
    return;
}
```

Here's the Swift Code:

```
func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral!,
    didUpdateValueForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic!,
    error: NSError!) -> String
{

    // Get the Heart Rate Monitor BPM
    var data = characteristic.value
    var reportData = data.bytes
    var bpm : UInt16
    var rawByte : UInt8
    var outputString = ""
    rawByte = UInt8(reportData[0])
    bpm = 0

    if ((rawByte & 0x01) == 0) {          // 2
        // Retrieve the BPM value for the Heart Rate Monitor
        bpm = UInt16( reportData[4] )
    }
    else {
        bpm = CFSwapInt16LittleToHost(UInt16(reportData[1]))
    }

    outputString = String(bpm)
    return outputString
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you changed `reportData[1];` to `UInt16( reportData[4] )` when converting to swift?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const uint8_t *reportData = [data bytes];
```

translates to

```
let reportData = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(data.bytes)
```

Then `reportData` has the type `UnsafePointer<UInt8>` and you can access it as in (Objective-)C:

```
if (reportData[0] & 0x01) == 0 { ... }
```

Next,

```
bpm = reportData[1];
```

is almost identical in Swift. You have to convert explicitly from `UInt8` to
`UInt16` because – unlike (Objective-)C – Swift does not implicitly convert between types:

```
bpm = UInt16(reportData[1])
```

Putting it together:

```
func getHeartBPMData(characteristic: CBCharacteristic!) {
    let data = characteristic.value
    let reportData = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(data.bytes)
    var bpm : UInt16
    if (reportData[0] & 0x01) == 0 {
        bpm = UInt16(reportData[1])
    } else {
        bpm = UnsafePointer<UInt16>(reportData + 1)[0]
        bpm = CFSwapInt16LittleToHost(bpm)
    }

    // ...
}
```

Note that most of your variables can be declared as *constants* with `let`, instead
of `var`. Instead of

```
bpm = CFSwapInt16LittleToHost(bpm)
```

you can alternatively use the `littleEndian:` constructor which is available
for all integer types:

```
bpm = UInt16(littleEndian: bpm)
```

---

**Update for Swift 3/4:**

```
func getHeartBPMData(characteristic: CBCharacteristic) {
    guard  let reportData = characteristic.value else {
        return 
    }

    let bpm : UInt16
    if (reportData[0] & 0x01) == 0 {
        bpm = UInt16(reportData[1])
    } else {
        bpm = UInt16(littleEndian: reportData.subdata(in: 1..<3).withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee } )
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! `let reportData = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(data.bytes)` is the real magic that I needed but I really appreciate your careful explanation.

Comment: For what its worth the working code is here: [https://github.com/tfenton/SwiftHRM.git](https://github.com/tfenton/SwiftHRM.git)