# Parsing NSData is crashes

Tags: swift

I get this data from BLE, but is crashes on certain values (I think when data is float )

function to get data :

```
  func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: NSError?) {

         print(characteristic); // prints a value always
         if characteristic.UUID == UUID_CHAR {

            if ( characteristic.value == nil)
            {return; }

             //***crash is here :
             let str:NSString = NSString(data: characteristic.value!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
            print ("got::",str);
```

This will crash when the characteristic is :

```
<CBCharacteristic: 0x157685860, UUID = FFE1, properties = 0x16, value = <00ff00>, notifying = YES>
```

and **not** when its this : (value field here is 00  )

```
<CBCharacteristic: 0x157685860, UUID = FFE1, properties = 0x16, value = <00>, notifying = YES>
```

I have tried wrapping it with `if let` , which did not worked.

```
ERROR: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

How would you cast the value to string, knowing it could be a **float** or integer ?

Comment: Not a duplicate at all, and does not have any connection to this question. I already wrote that I did tried to wrap the value .

Comment: `00ff00` is not a valid UTF-8 sequence, and therefore `NSString(data: characteristic.value!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)` returns `nil` and unwrapping that crashes. – `00ff00` also does not look like a floating point number to me (which usually would be 4 or 8 bytes). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/27949099/1187415 for an example how to access the bytes from the data.

Comment: @MartinR   Thanks I have tried that solution, it did not work, the thing is that you don't know what value you get, it might be a string, or a float, or an int ,  is there one way to do this right ? I can not find reliable solution.

Comment: Without any information you can only *guess* what `00 FF 00` represents. I am not an expert for Bluetooth communication, but I would assume that it is *documented* somewhere how the data is represented.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't need to cast to `NSString`, Then you don't have to forcefully `unwrap` the result. Try this:

```
let str = NSString(data: characteristic.value!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Now if the value is not a valid UTF-8 Sequence, You won't get a crash